# Transform date toString instead of UTC string

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, date, timezone

I have a node + typescript project. And am doing the following:

```
export class Slot {
  startTime: Date;
  constructor(_startTime: Date){
   this.startTime = _startTime
 }
}
// In some controller method

const slot = new Slot(new Date()); // Here the date is in the System Timzone
// Some logic for the Date object before sending the response
response.json(slot);
```

Now, in the response, the `startTime` is not retaining the systems `TZ`, its getting converted to UTC. *Its a requirement to send it in the System timezone.* I can manually do `.toString()` which will make it to the system timezone but want to avoid it as the `Date` object is getting processed a lot of places before sending it in the response.

Comment: Hi. I recommend checking your understanding of the `Date` object itself.  It doesn't retain any time zone.  It is simply a wrapper around a number - a Unix timestamp in terms of milliseconds, which is inherently UTC based.  Thus your comment "Here the date is in the System Timezone" is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

You can define [json replacer](http://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#app.settings.table) (the `replacer` argument used by [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#the_replacer_parameter)).

```
app.set('json replacer', function (key, value) {
  if (value instanceof Date) {
    // Apply required format
    return value.toLocaleString();
  }

  return value;
});
```